# I need to overwrite the value in property file

Tags: java

My property file contains 3 properties I need to overwrite the value for thirdOne. How do I load the property file from class path in my java code and overwrite it..

my property file Location packagName->resource->folderName->.propertyFile

**property File**: **I need to overwrite the value for "epochFromTime"**:

```
FILE_PATH=C:\\Users\\pda\\Desktop\\JsonOutput\\DataExtract
epochFilename=C:\\Users\\pda\\Desktop\\JsonOutput\\epochTime.txt
epochFromTime=1545329531862
```

**Java Code:**

```
try {
            Properties config = new Properties();
                config.load(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(PROPERTIES_PATH));
                String epochFromTimeChanged= Long.toString(epoch_to2);
                config.setProperty("epochFromTime",epochFromTimeChanged);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: What have you tried and what isn't working?

Comment: No it is not working. Can u please guide how do I make a use of FileOutputStream to do this?

Comment: There are many examples on the usage of OutputStream on SO.  I'm sure you can easily find them. For properties, if you cna use external libraries, [Apache Commons Configuration](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide/howto_properties.html) is made speciffcally to manage them.

Comment: Just saying "it is not working" does not help us in any way. Please check out the [ask] article and post a [mcve] that demonstrates the exact problem you're facing...

Comment: You are only loading your properties from a file, then change the value in memory. Your code does not save anything to a file and there is no reason to assume this just magically happens. You have to try something, not say "it's not working".

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty easy. First do read a property file to `Properties`. Then update it and save it afterwards. Do not forget to close resources.

```
public static void updateProperties(File file, Consumer<Properties> consumer) throws IOException {
    Properties properties = new Properties();

    try (Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
        properties.load(reader);
    }

    consumer.accept(properties);

    try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file))) {
        properties.store(writer, "comment");
    }

}
```

---

Client code could look like this:

```
updateProperties(
        new File("application.properties"),
        properties -> {
            properties.setProperty("two", "two_two_two");
            properties.setProperty("three", "three_three");
        });
```

---

**application.properties**

*before update*

```
two=two_two
one=one_one
```

*after update*

```
#comment
#Fri Jan 04 18:59:12 MSK 2019
two=two_two_two
one=one_one
three=three_three
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Properties.store()` to write the changed value back to the file:

```
String PROPERTIES_PATH = "...";
try {
    File f = new File(PROPERTIES_PATH);
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(f);
    Properties config = new Properties();
    config.load(in);

    String epochFromTimeChanged= Long.toString(epoch_to2);
    config.setProperty("epochFromTime",epochFromTimeChanged);

    // get or create the file
    File f = new File(PROPERTIES_PATH);
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f);
    config.store(out, "My properties file comment");

} catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
    log.info("{} does not exist", PROPERTIES_PATH);
} catch (IOException e) {
    log.error("Cannot access {}", PROPERTIES_PATH, e);
}
```